# direction ratio of a line in symmetric form

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

The equation of a line in cartesian form is: x-x1/a=y-y1/b/z-z1/c=r ,so is the direction ratio of the line a,b,c or ra,rb,rc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both represent the same ratio so both of them can be the direction ratio like For eg two parallel vectors have same direction ratio despite being scalar multiples of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Since the ratio a;b;c= ra:rb:rc therefore both give us the same details and either can be used as direction ratios.